# How to check that entered text is an email address? Android

Tags: android

Here is my code. Now I want to check this in if condition:

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) { boolean isValid = false;
String expression = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
  + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
  + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
  + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
  + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
  + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
CharSequence inputStr = email;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
if (!matcher.matches()) {
  isValid = true;
}
return isValid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st and your way**:

**try:** your **String expression Should be**

```
 String expression = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
+ "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
+ "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
+ "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
+ "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
+ "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
```

---

**2nd way**

**you can use**     `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(inputStr).matches()`

so your Method Should be

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {    
CharSequence inputStr = email;    
return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(inputStr).matches();
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS`, but note that expression in your 1st way is not correct - e.g. valid email: email@1.2.3.4 wouldn't be matched

Comment: @lopisan i use 2nd way ! thanks for pointing out, ohh its not working for  email@1.2.3.4 ! so, i have updated the answer as per your expression !

Comment: @Tarsem i m using this condition for check it further
else if (isEmailValid(email)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Email ID is not valid !.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

Comment: @GauravMehta ok good !

Comment: @taesem its not working it always goes through
if i enter abc then also it passes the condition
what i do now ?? :(

Comment: @GauravMehta it will return true if email is valid other wise it will return false so make sure you are using this code properly ! i am talking about 2nd and best way !

Comment: @terseem Sir can you give me the condition for your 2nd way :(
i mean can i use this
else if( isEmailValid("something@example.com") ) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email ID is not valid !.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // Email is valid
     }  
or something else :(

Comment: @GauravMehta dear you are doing wrong if you want to check that Email id is not Valid than it should be 
if(!isEmailValid("something@example.com") ) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email ID is not valid !.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} else {//Email id is valid }

Comment: @tarseem  

i m passing an intent from 
a button of activity1.java to activity2.java
a button of activity3.java to activity2.java
a button of activity4.java to activity2.java
now i have a back button in activity2.java
how i can guess that that the back button goes to activitya or activity3 or activity4
if you can post any code then please send
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry @GauravMehta i am unable to get this properly ! you can ask new question with relevant code that you tried !

Answer (score 1):

I would define your function like this:

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
  String expression = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
    + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
    + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
    + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
    + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
    + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(email);
  return matcher.matches();
}
```

And then test valid email like this:

```
if( isEmailValid("something@example.com") ) {
  // Email is valid
} else {
  // Email is not valid
}
```

PS: I didn't check the validity of your regexp, just arranged the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

why can not use this is the best way

```
boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
   return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the built in Patterns starting with API Level 8:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```